# FILE NOT FOUND when searching within text file

Tags: batch-file, file-not-found

I'm trying to write a batch file that will take a list of four-digit numbers from the file vlans.txt, search a given file *filename*, and if the string is found, append a line of text to file *newfile*.

I'm still working on the find portion of it but for now I have an annoying error where it's telling me it doesn't find *filename*.  Any ideas?

```
    ::@echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    :input
    set /p filename=Please enter the filename of the config file, including extension: || set filename=error
    if "%filename%"=="error" goto input

    :newfile
    set /p newfile=Enter the name of the file you wish to create:
    copy /y nul "%newfile%" >nul

    :parse
     FOR /F %%A IN (vlans.txt) DO (
     FIND /I "%%A" %filename%
     IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (ECHO "delete VLAN %%A" >> "%newfile%")
     )


     set filename=
     set newfile=
     set v=
```

Comment: `::@echo off` Since you have echo turned on (which btw is a good starting point for debugging), it should tell you what line causes the error, and the exact error message. Please post the full information, including what you enter at the `set /p` prompts..

Comment: @Shea Rook Please attach the full code or attach the contents of the vlan file. I am not able to duplicate the issue here.

Comment: Are you really sure `%filename%` exists at the location the script expects it?

Comment: Could fail if _filename_ contains `!` exclamation mark(s) in view of delayed expansion.

Comment: So I had a parenthesis out of place.  I moved it and it's finding the file now.  But for some reason it's not passing the value of A to the *ECHO "delete VLAN %%A"* part.  Back to the drawing board.